# When would I write E sharp and when would I write F natural?

Tags: theory, composition

My song is in E Major. The notes go as follows: A, G#, F#, E#/F natural, F#. My instinct is to do E# so that I don't have to put another accidental on the next note. Is there a specific reason to use one or the other? For it to fit a certain chord, for example?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, and has been closed, but if you're desperate for an answer nonetheless, use E#.